# How do I anonymise a mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial

I have a programming assignment I'm to hand in at my University for the end of this week and they have strict rules about anonymity of the assignments to maintain impartiality, so if my name (or any other obvious identifying info) appears anywhere in the work it may be automatically disqualified.

While preparing to burn everything to disc, I've just noticed/remembered that my HG repo is *full* of copies of my name. The code is all clean, but the author of every changeset is either my full name and email or my university login ID and the hostname of a lab computer (depends where I was working).

I need to create an anonymised version of the repo (or swap out all names for my student ID number) without losing any of the other information it holds.

So, as the headline says, how do I anonymise a mercurial repository?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Mercurial's [Convert extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) with the [`--authors` option](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--authors) to "convert" your repository into a new Mercurial repository, changing the authors' names during the conversion.

Quote from the second link:

> Convert can also remap author names during conversion, if the
>   `--authors` option is provided. The argument should be a simple text file maps each source commit author to a destination commit author. It
>   is handy for source SCMs that use UNIX logins to identify authors (eg:
>   CVS). Example:
>
> ```
> john=John Smith <John.Smith@someplace.net>
> tom=Tom Johnson <Tom.Johnson@bigcity.com>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this did the job nicely. A few points of warning for others though: (1) it seems you need to list all the user names separately and accurately (so needs a little work up front to collate) (2) the IDs of many changesets were modified (3) presumably because of 2, an additional changeset was created to fix the tags in the repo.

Comment: @DMA57361: 1) Use `hg log --template '{author}\n' | sort -u` to get a list of unique user names, 2) changeset IDs are formed using a cryptographic hash function (SHA-1) which (among other things) takes the user names as input, 3) Exactly right!

Comment: @MartinGeisler (1) would have helped yesterday :), but luckily I only had to collect 4 user names in this case so. (2) I was aware of, but thought I'd add it as a warning to future readers, as presumably it'll stop the converted repo ever being pushed/merged/etc back in to the original?

Comment: @DMA57361: Right, Mercurial will notice that the two repositories are "unrelated" since they don't have a common root node.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any merge changesets, then you could try using the `graft` command in Mercurial 2.0 to graft your repository to a new repository while changing the recorded user name.

If you do have merge changesets, then it might be possible to use the `transplant` extension in Mercurial 2.2, although changing the recorded user name appears to be harder.